# How to transfer uncompress video in YUY2 format with GStreamer

Tags: encoding, video-streaming, gstreamer-1.0

The rtpvrawpay accept the following formats on its sink pad: RGB, RGBA, BGR, BGRA, AYUV, UYVY, I420, Y41B, UYVP

My camera produces YUY2, which is very similar to UYVY.

How can I transfers YUY2 without pixelformat conversion?

Currently thinking of extending rtpvrawpay  & rtpvrawdepay to support YUY2 or writing a transform plugin that changes the format without doing any conversion.
Neither are particularly appealing...